# Converting to and from '<' and '>' automatically with Python

Tags: python, html

I use TextMate in Mac, and it allows me to program with Python just like emacs with Lisp.
The problem is the Python code is stored in XML in such a way that '>' and '<', characters are stored in &gt/&lt. I expect some other characters are changed.

How can I use python to convert those characters automatically? I could use string replace, but I expect some fundamental solutions from Python library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml:

```
import cgi
escaped = cgi.escape(unescaped)
```

Answer (score 2):

Load it with a lib like [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: If the Python is in XML, you should be getting it out of the XML with an XML parser, and the parser will handle the escaped characters for you.